# Can we please get text labels for the new OpenID registration form?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-interface, login, stack-exchange-openid

First off, I am quite pleased to see that [Stack Exchange is now an OpenID provider](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/stack-exchange-is-an-openid-provider). I see this as a very good thing for not only Stack Exchange but also the sites that will now be inspired to add OpenID support.

I decided to give it a spin, so I went [here](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register):

[image]

Unfortunately, I couldn't help but notice that there were no labels next to the form (which is certainly [recommended](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#introduction-1)). Although clear to me, some people may have trouble figuring out what "John Smith" means. (Indeed, I thought it was tradition to use "John Doe" in place of an actual name.)

Would it be possible to put form labels next to the input elements?

Comment: You are setting the bar **way** too high for annotated screenshots.

Comment: "John Doe" is more USA, "John Smith" is more English... no idea about other English speaking countries.

Comment: John Smith needs to choose a stronger password.

Answer (score -12):

No. We want the form to be as simple as possible, and the "labels" are already overlaid on the fields.

Comment: Examples are not labels. And would these even work for someone who is visually impaired?

Comment: "Email address", "Name" would be labels.

Comment: I'm really surprised at this answer. Are you planning to change all the other forms on the entire website to match this model? Can we just admit this is the way it is because it's how it went through development and testing? There's nothing wrong with that. Now that it's in production, it needs a bit of polishing.

Comment: I think the push for usability (including `<label for` semantics) is the only useful argument that can be made. Otherwise everyone here is arguing that we should help the sort of users we don't want to stick around. I for one +1 this answer.

Comment: How well does the form works with "jaws" and other screan readers

Comment: @jcole: That's **exactly** what I'm saying (using `<label>` for semantics).

Comment: @IanRingrose yeah, screen readers is part of what I meant wrt usability.

Comment: @jcole I suppose we can have hidden `<label>` elements for screen readers, if necessary.

Comment: @Jeff that is the only reason I see to change it personally. I personally hold your position.